# Travis build fails in Yeoman Angular generated app

Tags: travis-ci, compass-sass, yeoman-generator

I'm not being able to build an angular application generated with Yeoman using `angular-generator`. It fails when uses compass gem. I've already added the compass gem installation to the build descriptor.

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.8'
  - '0.10'
before_script:
  - 'gem update --system'
  - 'gem install compass'
  - 'npm install -g bower grunt-cli'
  - 'bower install'
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Warning: /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved similar problem following [this link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/130).

In short, I put the following versions in the .travis.yml file:

```
'gem install sass --version "=3.2.12"'
'gem install compass --version "=0.12.2"'
```